# Javascript or JQuery code for displaying image only between 9:00am - 11:00am?

Tags: javascript, time

I need a Javascript or JQuery code for displaying an image on a webpage only between 9:00am - 11:00am everyday according to the user's local time.

In other words, time based display div javascript.

Comment: Sweet!  What have you tried?

Comment: Starting point [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Do you need it to display up through 10:59:59, or including exactly 11:00:00?

Comment: -1 as this question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, via [`Date.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours), check if it is between 9 and 11.

```
// Current local hour via new Date().getHours();
var h = new Date().getHours();
if (h >= 9 && h < 11) {
  yourElement.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
  yourElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Or jQuery:

```
if (h >= 9 && h < 11) {
  $(yourSelector).show();
}
else {
  $(yourSelector).hide();
}
```

Comment: Don't know what's wrong with me that I took 3 edits to get the `<>` comparisons right...

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes as I've discovered after about 9 attempts :(

Comment: `< 11` will go up to 10:59, asking OP for clarification about 11:00;